# Keras unreasonnably slower than TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to implement the neural network of [this TensorFlow example](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/pros), but using Keras.

You'll find the code for both implementations at the bottom of the post.

My problem is that the code takes around 1m30 with TensorFlow, and 18 minutes with Keras !

My question is :

- Did I make a rookie mistake in translating TensorFlow code to Keras code ?
- Or is Keras incredibly slow ? If so, can it be fixed ?

---

Tensorflow code :

```python
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

import tensorflow as tf

def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784]) 
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, 28, 28, 1]) 

y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10]) 

neurons_nb_layer_1 = 32
neurons_nb_layer_2 = 64
neurons_nb_layer_3 = 1024

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, neurons_nb_layer_1]) 
b_conv1 = bias_variable([neurons_nb_layer_1]) 

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1) 
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1) 

W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, neurons_nb_layer_1, neurons_nb_layer_2])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([neurons_nb_layer_2])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2) 

W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * neurons_nb_layer_2, neurons_nb_layer_3])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([neurons_nb_layer_3])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * neurons_nb_layer_2]) 
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1) 


keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

W_fc2 = weight_variable([neurons_nb_layer_3, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(
    tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_, logits=y_conv))

train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv, 1), tf.argmax(y_, 1)) 
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32)) 

import datetime
start = datetime.datetime.now()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  for i in range(600):
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
    if i % 100 == 0:
      train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
          x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 1.0})
      print('step %d, training accuracy %g' % (i, train_accuracy))
    train_step.run(feed_dict={x: batch[0], y_: batch[1], keep_prob: 0.5})

  print('test accuracy %g' % accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
      x: mnist.test.images, y_: mnist.test.labels, keep_prob: 1.0}))
end = datetime.datetime.now()
time = (end - start).seconds
print(time//60, "min", time%60,"s")
```

---

Keras code :

```python
from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True)

import keras
from keras.models import Sequential

model = Sequential()

bias_initializer = keras.initializers.Constant(value = 0.1)

neurons_nb_layer_1 = 32
neurons_nb_layer_2 = 64
neurons_nb_layer_3 = 1024

from keras.layers import Reshape, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dropout, Flatten, Dense
model.add(Reshape((28, 28, 1), input_shape=(784,)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = neurons_nb_layer_1, kernel_size = 5*5, padding = 'same', activation = "relu", bias_initializer = bias_initializer))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = neurons_nb_layer_2, kernel_size = 5*5, padding = 'same', activation = "relu", bias_initializer = bias_initializer))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(padding='same'))
model.add(Reshape((1,7*7*neurons_nb_layer_2)))
model.add(Dense(units = neurons_nb_layer_3, activation = "relu", bias_initializer = bias_initializer))
model.add(Dropout(rate = 0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units = 10, activation = "relu"))

model.summary()

model.compile(loss = keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              optimizer = 'adam',
              metrics=['accuracy']
              )


import datetime
start2 = datetime.datetime.now()
for i in range(600):
    batch = mnist.train.next_batch(50)
    if i % 100 == 0:
        train_accuracy = model.evaluate(batch[0], batch[1])
        print("step", i, ":", train_accuracy)
    model.train_on_batch(batch[0], batch[1])
end2 = datetime.datetime.now()
time2 = (end2 - start2).seconds
print(time2//60, "min", time2%60,"s")
```

Comment: Probably irrelevant, but you should change the activation in your last Keras layer to `softmax`.

Comment: Also, for comparison, Keras own [MNIST example](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/master/examples/mnist_cnn.py) might be useful

Comment: Whats your gear? CPU/GPU, memory available?
Are you running these two codes sequentially, in the same python execution?

Answer (score 5):

according to [keras documentation](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2d) `kernel_size = 5*5` is a `25x25` convolution kernel, not `5x5` like your tensorflow example
you might want to use `kernel_size=(5,5)` or `kernel_size=5`

Comment: Indeed, this might be the problem ! I'll try it when I'm on my on my computer at home and will let you know. Thanks.